# Maxwell's demon - scaling down from something that seems to work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

### [I have updated the below description to clarify that the mechanism does not depend on a truly frictionless implementation.  Also, since 2 commenters apparently assumed that I was proposing a mechanism to create energy from nothing, it seems necessary to state that this is **not** what I am proposing.]

I will describe a Maxwell's Demon like mechanism that seems to extract useful work from random motion at a human scale.  The questions that I then have about this mechanism are:
  1) Does it work?  If not, in what way does it fail?
  2) If we scale this mechanism down (towards the scale at which the balls in the example can be replaced with atmospheric molecules), at what scale does it first stop working, and why?

MECHANISM:  A rigid cylinder (say, 2m in diameter and 10m in length) floats in space.   Inside are 10^5 1-cm elastic massive balls colliding at random.  There is a piston in the cylinder, consisting of a rigid circular disk which just fits inside the cylinder, welded to a thin rigid rod.  The rod runs along the cylinder's axis, through the disk, and extends through holes in the center of the cylinder's ends.  This piston can slide with low friction along the axis of the cylinder.  The disk is perforated by many 5-cm holes, each of which is covered with a light, rigid hinged trap door, weakly spring-loaded and damped so as to close after being opened.  Each trap door is one-way:  When initially closed, it is easily pushed aside allowing Northbound balls to pass through, but it reflects Southbound balls.  The disk is initially positioned midway along the cylinder, with **half of the balls on each side of the disk**.

ANALYSIS:  The piston will move under the influence of a net Southward force due to the randomly bouncing balls, because **Southbound** balls encountering a hole will typically rebound from its trap door transferring considerable momentum to the disk, while **Northbound** balls will typically pass through, transferring little momentum to the disk.  This motion is transferred outside the cylinder by the rod, where it can perform useful work.

Comment: Fallacy: __without friction__. This can never be achieved practically.

Comment: Even if this works it only gives you back the energy stored in the motion of the balls.  How'd they get moving in the first place?

Comment: And what happens after they lose all their energy?

Comment: Brandon, Pranav, regarding your comments that the energy harvested would derive from (and couldn't exceed) the balls' energy of motion:  Thanks.  I agree, but that isn't responsive to my questions; I wasn't trying to describe a mechanism that creates energy from nothing, but rather one that harvests useful energy from random motion.

Comment: Pranav  (not sure how comment responses work but this is in response to your comment concerning frictionlessness):  Thanks.  I specified perfect frictionlessness, elasticity, and rigidity to simplify the analysis.  An actual implementation could not achieve these, but as it approaches them, the conclusion would appear to still apply.

Comment: All you've really described here  is a hot gas under pressure.  Yes the pressure would push a piston. The fact that it's made out of steel balls doesn't really change the concept.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.  But to follow through on your analogy:  Note that in my example, the "gas" starts out equally hot and with equal pressure on each side of the piston.  Does **that** "change the concept"?

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas.  It sounds as though you agree that the mechanism I describe **will** harvest useful work from the balls' random motion **if** I add an explicit damper so that the door doesn't bounce back and forth forever (I will make that update).  Correct?  I am less clear on the implications of the 'temperature' of the door as we scale the mechanism down, however.  Is it possible for you to state your observation in strictly mechanical, as opposed to thermodynamic, terms?  If it is valid this should be possible, and also more intuitive for thermodynamic illiterates such as me:-)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this has nothing to do with friction !

The key point in your setup is the 'temperature' of the *gate*.

If it is at the same temperature as the balls, it will be jumping around (like the balls) and therefore it won't be able to correctly select the balls it lets through.

If it is cold (fixed) then you *do* have a cold source (hence a temperature difference you can extract work from). Note that randomly bouncing off some balls will transfer momentum to the gate : if you start with a cold gate you end up heating it...

Comment: Thanks Nicolas!  It sounds as though you agree that the mechanism I describe would harvest useful work from the balls' random motion if I add an explicit damper so that the door doesn't bounce back and forth forever.  Correct?

Comment: correct, but this doesnt violate the 2nd law since your damper would merely transfer heat to a laeger reservoir.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meat of the problem is summarized neatly by the [ratchet-and-pawl mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_ratchet) which Feynman talks about in his lectures on physics. [Here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/molcomplectures/MolecularRobotics/BrownianRatchetMolMotors/Feynman.V1Ch46Ratchet&Pawl.pdf) is a textbook treatment.

Comment: Thanks, the ratchet/pawl explanation is exactly the kind of thing I am looking for!  (Ironically I actually read this long ago, but have no memory of the paragraph which mentions spring loaded trap doors.)  I dont

Comment: The ratchet/pawl explanation is exactly the kind I am looking for!  (Ironically I actually read this long ago, but have zero memory of the paragraph mentioning spring loaded trap doors.)  I don't yet see how the ratchet/pawl analysis can be applied to hot **one-way** trap doors, so I must ponder that (it seems to me that even flapping wildly, such a door would preferentially harvest Southbound momentum).  And I don't yet fully get the more general argument from reversibility (e.g. I don't see where he **uses** his assumption that the system is "complicated enough").  But awesome, thx!

Comment: I think the problem is that as long as your mechanism functions as it is supposed to, it is still "cold". We don't really have a good intuition for macroscopic machines behaving thermally, and temperature is really an idealization when you are talking about numbers so small ($10^5$ is small). Anyway, very roughly, the "open" state of the trap door has probability $e^{-\frac{E}{k_B T}}$, which, as $T$ gets large enough, approaches 1.

Comment: thanks again.  I still want to better understand (in mechanical terms and w/o any quote marks:-) the conditions under which the trap door approach works and does not work.  So I will think about your further hint in the spirit of the Feynman ratchet/pawl analysis (including its scale dependence).  (I must also think more about Feynman's more general argument, because that seems the only way to avoid spending one's life dealing with characters like me who come forward w/ ever more Rube Goldberg-ish proposals along these lines:-)